# elasticsearch - how to make bucket filter in java api

Tags: elasticsearch, bucket

I made some elasticsearch query like below and it works well.

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "agg_sum" : {
      "sum" : {
        "field" : "cnt"
      }
    },
    "bucket_filter": {
        "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "totalSales": "agg_sum"
            },
            "script": "totalSales >= 10"
        }
    }
  }
```

It needed to be converted as java api query, but don't know how to convert "buckets_filter". any idea of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BucketSelector` in java api would be like this:

```
Map<String, String> bucketsPathsMap = new HashMap<>();
        bucketsPathsMap.put("ags", "agg_sum");
        Script script = new Script("params.ags > 10");

   BucketSelectorPipelineAggregationBuilder bs =
                PipelineAggregatorBuilders.bucketSelector("bucket_filter", bucketsPathsMap, script);
AggregationBuilders.subAggregation(bs);
```

this is probably too late, just for sake of same problem.